# Windows batch remove string and newline

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have a file that, after a lot of playing around with windows batch, I managed to get the output in this format:

```
checksum=d0ea0cf465e3cdaws42d43fc3c5b17 *file_1020.csv
|mode=standard
```

I need to remove the  *file_1020.csv and the trailing newline to get the output in a single line:

```
checksum=d0ea0cf465e3cdaws42d43fc3c5b17|mode=standard
```

Can you help me with the command that does this, I have searched and tried several things like set /p but none of them worked. My code is

```
echo|set /p="checksum=">file_1020.csv_tmp 
md5sum file_1020.csv>>file_1020.csv_tmp 
echo|set /p="|mode=standard" < nul >> file_1020.csv_tmp
```

Comment: What you need is a `for /F` loop: `(for /F %%I in ('md5sum "file_2010.csv"') do echo checksum=%%I^|mode=standard) > "file_2020.csv_tmp"`…

Comment: @aschipfl You are a savior. And to think I spent 3 hours with this windows batch scripting :|

Comment: @aschipfl I get an extra back slash \ when I specify the path as C:\Temp\file_1020.csv. So output is checksum=\d0ea0c... Can you help?

Comment: `(for /F "delims=\ " %%I …` (the rest is just the same)…